# XmlReaderParsingException: The start element with name <...> and namespace "http..." was unexpected

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk, biztalk-2010

This is for BizTalk 2010.  I am running into a very strange issue that I've not been able to find a solution either using my favorite search engine's results or elsewhere.

I added several SQL Server 2008 table schemas to BizTalk.  Set up orchestration and mapping without any problems.  BizTalk was able to use WCF_Custom SQL Adapter using XML/BTSAction to insert data to the SQL tables identified in the XML.

Some of those tables had data inserted just fine, except two.  Both had the same error.  The error was pulling from a third table's namespace.  Here's the error in full -- notice that the namespace, ns, is for ns46:professionalAddendum as is expected, but somehow, somewhere, BizTalk is pulling a different namespace, ns35, from a different table:

Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: The start element with name "ClaimFilingIndicatorCode" and namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/professionalCOBAdjustmentsAncillary" was unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.

```
<ns2:Insert xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/professionalAddendum">
  <ns2:Rows>
    <ns46:professionalAddendum xmlns:ns46="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo">
      <ns46:uid_claim>1b8f20e9-0517-4f00-9ee2-99d5f04d1573</ns46:uid_claim>
ERROR>>>>>   <ns35:ClaimFilingIndicatorCode xmlns:ns35="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/professionalCOBAdjustmentsAncillary">17</ns35:ClaimFilingIndicatorCode>
      <ns46:ClaimFrequencyTypeCode>1</ns46:ClaimFrequencyTypeCode>
      <ns46:ProviderAcceptAssignmentCode>B</ns46:ProviderAcceptAssignmentCode>
      <ns46:BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>Y</ns46:BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>
      <ns46:ReleaseofCode>Y</ns46:ReleaseofCode>
      <ns46:ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>N</ns46:ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>
    </ns46:professionalAddendum>
  </ns2:Rows>
</ns2:Insert>
```

Is there a way to fix this?  Really weird.

Thanks all!

Comment: As per Schellack's answer, any slight deviation from the XSD can cause this. [This post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5dc56c8c-4d39-4dd1-8465-ec5eafe20360/calling-a-sproc-error-with-start-element-and-namespace) describes a way of scraping the xml message that BTS is trying to send, which can then be validated against the XSD.

Comment: StuartLC, thanks for your reply.  I removed every single TableOperation schemas, and re-imported them via the Add Generated Item -> Consume Adapter Service, then rebuilt a master table schema listing every single table.  I still got the same problem -- different namespace numbers this time around.

The interesting thing is that an earlier block had the correct namespace # for ClaimFilingIndicatorCode, but then changed to a different one with the subsequent block, then the 3rd block, it'd revert back to the correct one... and so on.  Very strange.  Never saw this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting up what I found. The map and orchestration are both fine for the most part. There was a Scripting functoid in the mapper that used an inline XSLT to map from the source schema to the destination schema, and the offending namespace was in that XSLT code. When I changed the schema's tables, their corresponding namespace #s changed as well thus causing this problem to manifest itself. Having said that, I fixed it up to be flexible should the schema tables' namespace #s change again.

Problem solved. Now I got to fix up a few of those. :)

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to know exactly what is going on without seeing your full schema, but I have seen it where the case of a table name changes somewhere, and then the corresponding namespace no longer matches.

For example:
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/professionalAddendum`
vs
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/ProfessionalAddendum`

Comment: I updated the project by removing the 3rd table from BizTalk.  It still failed by finding another table to pull that particular field from.  I'm still investigating...

Comment: If you are still getting an error about an unrecognized namespace, perhaps you could manually edit the schema for the table operation and just define the namespace there?

Comment: schellack, the funny thing is that when I removed the "new schemas" from the project (I have a few others in place), it worked fine.  Any new table that I introduce to BizTalk gets the above.